# How to write type for filter function in Typescript avoiding overload error?

Tags: typescript

I've this kind of situation:

```
type TMapStateToProps = (state: TObjectAny, props: {resource: string, namespace: string }) => ({
  savedFilters: TObjectAny
});

export const mapStateToProps: TMapStateToProps = (state, { resource, namespace = '_' }) => {
return {
    savedFilters: Object.values(
      get(state, 'admin.resources.settings/user-data.data', {})
    )
      .filter((({ key_name }: any): boolean => key_name === getSavedFiltersKey(resource, namespace)))
      .reduce((prev: any, cur: any) => {
        try {
          const filter = JSON.parse(cur.data.filter);
          prev[cur._id] = {
            name: cur.data.name,
            filter,
          };
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }

        return prev;
      }, {}),

  };
};
```

What come up from
`Object.values(get(state, 'admin.resources.settings/user-data.data', {}))` is an empty object or an array of objects where each object has this structure:

```
type TObjectFilter = {
 created_at: string,
 data: TObjectAny
 id: string,
 key_name: string,
 public: boolean,
 updated_at: string,
 user: string,
 _id: string,
}
```

If I use
`filter((({ key_name }: any): boolean => key_name === getSavedFiltersKey(resource, namespace)))`
so with `any`, everything is working, but I would like to use the correct type and write:
`filter((({ key_name }: {key_name:string}): boolean => key_name === getSavedFiltersKey(resource, namespace)))`

In this case I'm getting the following error in filter function:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(predicate: (value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) => value is unknown, thisArg?: any): unknown[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '({ key_name }: { key_name: string; }) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) => value is unknown'.
      Types of parameters '__0' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ key_name: string; }'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(predicate: (value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): unknown[]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '({ key_name }: { key_name: string; }) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[]) => unknown'.
      Types of parameters '__0' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ key_name: string; }'.
```

I'm quiet new with TS, I spent a lot time looking around, I found some similar questions related with the predicate and casting type, I tried to apply to my case but with no success unfortunately, could someone help me and maybe explain me the solution please?
Thank you!

Comment: Your array is not homogenous. You have a TObj, and another object that lacks an `a` property (so is not a TObj) and an unknown `b` property, and you have to defined your filter callback *only* to take a TObj, so the compiler rightly complains. Either use an array of all TObj or define your filter function to take different inputs.

Comment: You're right, actually I was trying to simplify the problem, but I came up with not suitable example, I'll modify the situation up.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is not homogenous that doesn't mean it can't be typed but if you want to approach condition the key_name is the name of the first property it is more difficult. Try this:

```
type TObj<T extends string> = Record<T, number> & Record<"key_name", T>;

const testArray: [TObj<"a">, TObj<"b">, TObj<"c">] = [
    {
        a: 1,
        key_name: 'a',
    },
    {
        b: 2,
        key_name: 'b',
    },
    {
        c: 3,
        key_name: 'c'
    }
];

testArray.filter(obj => obj.key_name === "a);
```

But this doesn't solve the use of any, for testFn you should use `TObject<any>`

So for this problem, it's impossible.

Comment: Sorry, I modified my post, since as you guys made me notice, I was trying to simplify the problem and I made a stupid error.